# three.js: Manually created geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a THREE.Geometry from scratch.
When I try to use it (in a THREE.Mesh), I get

> TypeError: faces3 is undefined @ three.js:20426

The geometry is created and becomes visible on screen, <strike>but execution stops</strike>.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
makePlane = function(width, height)
{
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

    var v0 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(width, 0, 0);
    var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(width, height, 0);

    geom.vertices.push(v0);
    geom.vertices.push(v1);
    geom.vertices.push(v2);

    var face = new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2);

    geom.faces.push(face);

    return geom;
};
```

What else do I need to do to make it work?

**Update:**
Still happens in R62. It happens with geometry generated by three.js' built in PlaneGeometry class too, so maybe it's a three.js bug. I'll file a report.

I should also mention that execution does in fact **not** stop, that was a mistake on my part. I'm just getting the error, and it doesn't feel like I should have any errors if nothing is  wrong.

**Update 2:**
There's an issue logged [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1907), but it's been closed.

Comment: can you post runnable code, just want to check if geom is plugged into a mesh and also the position and size are within the view frustrum(visible)

Comment: @George Actually I can't reproduce the error in a clean script, but the code I'm actually using is in the first few lines here: https://github.com/tacospice/tacosjs/blob/master/js/engine/Entity/Plane.js

Comment: I see, what width/height dimensions did you test ?

Comment: 25x25, 13x3, and some others of similar size

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you do in further computation steps you may need to add these lines before you return the geom-Object:

```
geom.computeCentroids();
geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();
```

Comment: geom.computeCentroids(); is gone

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you are using the latest version of the three.js library.

In order for geometry to work, you need to make sure you have a few things set up.
You need to have a **renderer**, **camera**, **scene**, and your **geometry**.

Based on the documentation for [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry), you need to provide a method to do something with the geometry afterwards such as `computeCentroids()` and `computeBoundingBox()`.

Returning the value is not necessary here. It will actually prevent your object from showing up. Here is fully functional code for you based on your code. Just make sure your three.js reference is correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Custom Geometry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var container,
            camera,
            scene,
            renderer,
            geom;

        init();

        function init() {
            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            //renderer
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); //Use CanvasRenderer with simple geometry
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            //scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            //camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
            camera.position.z = 500;

            //Your custom geometry here
            makePlane(200, 300);

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

        function makePlane(width, height) {

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x297bbb });
            geom = new THREE.Geometry()

            geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(width, 0, 0));
            geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(width, height, 0));

            geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

            //return geom; //you don't need this

            geom.computeBoundingSphere(); //<--add what you need here

            geoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material); //added custom geometry to a mesh with a material
            geoMesh.position.y = -50;

            scene.add(geoMesh);
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I don't return the generated geometry, how am I going to use it anywhere? I'd get undefined back.

Comment: @tacospice I have updated my answer with functional code. I'm sure this would help you get started.